# Is there any use cases where other DNS classes are useful apart INTERNET?

Tags: dns, rfc, dig

`IN`(ternet) class is the default one.

I know another useful one, `CHAOS` :

censurfridns :

```
% dig @91.239.100.100 version.bind TXT CHAOS +short
"9.11.4-P2+dampening"
```

Are the other ones have a use case ?

- `CS` aka `CSNET` class (Obsolete)
- `HS` aka `Hesiod` [Dyer 87]

From http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2929.html

> RR CLASS IANA Considerations
>
> DNS CLASSes have been little used but constitute another dimension
>   of    the DNS distributed database.  In particular, there is no
>   necessary    relationship between the name space or root servers for
>   one CLASS and    those for another CLASS.  The same name can have
>   completely different    meanings in different CLASSes although the
>   label types are the same    and the null label is usable only as root
>   in every CLASS.  However,    as global networking and DNS have
>   evolved, the IN, or Internet, CLASS    has dominated DNS use.
>
> There are two subcategories of DNS CLASSes: normal data containing 
>   classes and QCLASSes that are only meaningful in queries or updates.
>
> The current CLASS assignments and considerations for future
>   assignments are as follows:
>
> ```
>  Decimal    Hexadecimal
>
>  0    0x0000 - assignment requires an IETF Standards Action.
>
>  1    0x0001 - Internet (IN).
>
>  2    0x0002 - available for assignment by IETF Consensus as a data CLASS.
>
>  3    0x0003 - Chaos (CH) [Moon 1981].
>
>  4    0x0004 - Hesiod (HS) [Dyer 1987].
>
>  5 - 127    0x0005 - 0x007F - available for assignment by IETF Consensus as data
>       CLASSes only.
>
>  128 - 253    0x0080 - 0x00FD - available for assignment by IETF Consensus as
>       QCLASSes only.
>
>  254    0x00FE - QCLASS None [RFC 2136].
>
>  255    0x00FF - QCLASS Any [RFC 1035].
>
>  256 - 32767    0x0100 - 0x7FFF - assigned by IETF Consensus.
>
>  32768 - 65280    0x8000 - 0xFEFF - assigned based on Specification Required as defined
>       in [RFC 2434].
>
>  65280 - 65534    0xFF00 - 0xFFFE - Private Use.
>
>  65535    0xFFFF - can only be assigned by an IETF Standards Action.
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All other ones are basically now obsolete and not used.

See https://miek.nl/2009/july/31/dns-classes/ for some explanations, like:

> The CH class has its use in the Chaosnet, which is a network implementation that didn’t make it, unlike the current Ethernet + TCP/IP combo. [..] Today the CH class is missused by BIND, for the following neat tricks: ...

and

> The HS class has its origins Project Athena (also see Wikipedia. Which is a naming server ala nis or more recent ldap. With HS class you can put user and group data in your DNS, so you can do without an ldap server. The package hesiod still can be installed if you want to play with this.

[Section 3.2 of RFC2929](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2929#section-3.2) (september 2000!) already says:

> DNS CLASSes have been little used but constitute another dimension of
> the DNS distributed database. [..] However,
> as global networking and DNS have evolved, the IN, or Internet, CLASS
> has dominated DNS use.

It is widely believed now that the DNS specification is not clear enough regarding classes and how much they are isolated one from another.

This latest document (https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-sullivan-dns-class-useless-03.html) in July 2016 gives explanations on the current status and what to do in the future:

> Domain Name System Resource Records are identified in part by their class. The class field is not effective, and it is not used the way it appears to have been intended. This memo makes no recommendation about the DNS parameters registry, but urges those defining new RRTYPEs to define them for all classes.

> [..]

> As of this writing, there are only three "ordinary" classes assigned. Class 1 is the Internet or IN class. Class 3 is the Chaos or CH class. Class 4 is the Hesiod or HS class. Class 2 is noted in [RFC1035] as the CSNET or CS class, but the current registry (at http://www.iana.org/assignments/dns-parameters/dns-parameters.xml#dns-parameters-2) no longer includes the assignment.

> [..]

> 3. DNS classes are effectively vestigial
>
> Given the considerations above, it is plain that DNS classes are unlikely to be useful in the future. Designers of new name systems should consider the design of classes in the DNS. If a similar feature is desirable, its design needs to be different in order to be useful. Given the the way the DNS has managed to thrive effectively without classes, however, it would be worth asking whether the feature is useful at all.

You can find a lot of discussions on it, specifically in the IETF Working Group `dnsop` that cater for these topics:

- https://www.mail-archive.com/dnsop@ietf.org/msg14877.html
- https://www.iab.org/mail-archive/web/inip-discuss/current/msg00060.html

This specific Internet-Draft is also referenced in [RFC 8324 - DNS Privacy, Authorization, Special Uses, Encoding, Characters, Matching, and Root Structure: Time for Another Look?](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8324)
as [Sullivan-Class] in:

> In recent years, demand for new and extended services and uses of the
> DNS have, in turn, led to proposals for DNS extensions or changes of
> various sorts.  [..]  A
> few features of the original DNS specification, such as the CLASS
> property and label types, have also been suggested to be so badly
> specified that they should be deprecated [Sullivan-Class].

and

> 3.6.  Alternate Namespaces for Public Use in the DNS Framework: The
> CLASS Problem

> The DNS standards include specification of a CLASS value, which    "identifies a protocol family or instance of a protocol" (RFC 1034,    Section 3.6, and elsewhere).  While CLASS was used effectively in the  early days of the DNS to manage different protocol families within    the same administrative environment, recent attempts to use it to    either partition the DNS namespace in other ways such as for    non-ASCII names (partially to address the issues in Sections 3.2 and 3.3) or use DNS mechanisms for entirely different namespaces have    exposed fundamental problems with the mechanism [Sullivan-Class].    Perhaps the most fundamental of those problems is disagreement about   whether multiple CLASSes were intended to exist within a given zone    (with records within RRSETs) or whether different CLASSes implied    different zones.  Different implementations make different    assumptions [Faltstrom-2004] [Vixie-20170704].  These problems have    led to recommendations that it be dropped entirely [Sullivan-Class],   but discussions on the IETF list and in WGs in mid-2017 made it clear  that there is no clear consensus on that matter.